# Trying to extract annual sales data into 1 record, getting two instead

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use a query to extract sales data from 2017 and 2018. I can do this using a case statement, but the table is creating two records for each customer (one for 17, one for 18). How can I keep them in the same record?

```
SELECT     KPI_OPS_ALL.OPS, KPI_OPS_ALL.CustNo, Customer.Name1,     Customer.Address, Customer.City, CASE year(closeddate) 
            WHEN 2017 THEN SUM(KPI_OPS_ALL.Sales) END AS sales17, CASE year (closeddate) WHEN 2018 THEN SUM(KPI_OPS_ALL.Sales) END AS sales18
FROM         KPI_OPS_ALL LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Customer ON KPI_OPS_ALL.CustNo = Customer.CustNo
WHERE     (KPI_OPS_ALL.OPS = 'Dave')
GROUP BY KPI_OPS_ALL.CustNo, Customer.Name1, Customer.Address, Customer.City, KPI_OPS_ALL.OPS, YEAR(KPI_OPS_ALL.ClosedDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation, where the `case` expression is the argument to `sum()`.  Then you can fix the `group by`:

```
SELECT KPI_OPS_ALL.OPS, KPI_OPS_ALL.CustNo, Customer.Name1,  Customer.Address, Customer.City,
       SUM(CASE WHEN year(closeddate) = 2017 THEN KPI_OPS_ALL.Sales END) AS sales17,
       SUM(CASE WHEN year(closeddate) = 2018 THEN KPI_OPS_ALL.Sales END) AS sales18
FROM  KPI_OPS_ALL LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Customer
      ON KPI_OPS_ALL.CustNo = Customer.CustNo
WHERE KPI_OPS_ALL.OPS = 'Dave'
GROUP BY KPI_OPS_ALL.CustNo, Customer.Name1, Customer.Address, Customer.City, KPI_OPS_ALL.OPS;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the explanation. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some aliases and formatting to make your queries a lot easier to decipher. You can solve this with conditional aggregation.

Something like this should be pretty close. Notice I removed the YEAR from the group by.

```
SELECT a.OPS
    , a.CustNo
    , c.Name1
    , c.Address
    , c.City
    , MAX(CASE year(closeddate) WHEN 2017 THEN SUM(a.Sales) END) AS sales17
    , MAX(CASE year (closeddate) WHEN 2018 THEN SUM(a.Sales) END) AS sales18
FROM KPI_OPS_ALL a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer c ON a.CustNo = c.CustNo
WHERE a.OPS = 'Dave'
GROUP BY a.CustNo
    , c.Name1
    , c.Address
    , c.City
    , a.OPS
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! Also great tip on the formatting - will use in the future. Have a great day!

Comment: The formatting is nice but the code I posted has some issues. Don't use this, instead use Gordon's.